# Completely move from Joomla to Wordpress using same domain and server

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I'm trying to move my site from Joomla to Wordpress. I'm not a developer and I'm not that well versed with Joomla. I've already recreated the entire site in Wordpress and I don't care too much about SEO. I've had a look at the migration plugin in WP but it's not doing what I need it to do.

Currently, my Joomla site address is: http://myfakesite.com/index.php?lang=en. My WP site resides at http://myfakesite.com/wp/

I've already tried the redirection option from within Joomla but it's not working.

I intend to completely remove Joomla from my server and its database too. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WP all import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) free plugin by [Soflyy](http://soflyy.com/).
Its very good way for transfer data with true format,

For first you must export all Joomla data in XML file,

I think its easy. You can find plugin from [this link](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/?start=18)

Comment: Thank you for the update but I'm not interested in the data from Joomla. I want to make the url now direct to the Wordpress instance.